# How do I access geotags in iphone-pictures

Tags: iphone, geolocation, uiimage

I am trying to access the gps-coordinates stored in the metadata of a picture taken with the iphones camera. I can extract some information from the picture (colorspace, resolution etc) but i cant seem to get to the geotag. How do I do this?

I access the meta data using this line of code:

```
NSDictionary *metaData = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
```

where "info" is the `NSDictionary` reurned by `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 2):

There are a list of keys available from Apple, for images that have Global Positioning Information.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html

I would assume you are interested mainly in:

```
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude;
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude;
```